# Can't get session.gc.lifetime

Tags: php

I am trying to find out the maxtime for my php session (I don't have access to the cpanel or php.ini file). I am trying to use this code but its not printing out anything (except 'hello'). Whats wrong?

```
 <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting",1);

// Get the current Session Timeout Value
 $currentTimeoutInSecs = ini_get(’session.gc_maxlifetime’);
 print "hello " . $currentTimeoutInSecs;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong kind of quotes, use straight single or double quotes:

```
$currentTimeoutInSecs = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

Comment: This makes me curious, would PHP be attempting to interpret `"’session.gc_maxlifetime’"` as a constant?

Answer (score 1):

Use single ticks (and not single quotes) in your code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("error_reporting",1);

  // Get the current Session Timeout Value
  $currentTimeoutInSecs = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
  print "hello " . $currentTimeoutInSecs;
?>
```

Output:

> hello 84600